# How do I restrict access to a directory for a specific user through samba?

Tags: server, samba

I have got a sub directory of a shared directory that I use Samba with and have set it to be accessible by only one user:

```
$ cd /mnt/SomeSambaShare 
$ ls -lad SomeDir
drwx--S--- 23 SomeUser SomeGroup 4096 2012-07-26 07:44 SomeDir
```

I cannot access this directory as a linux user other than SomeUser.

But I still can access this directory using a different Samba user than SomeUser. Why is that? And how do I prevent this?

Comment: Could you provide the relevant lines from your `smb.conf`? I assume you can do some tweaking there.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and really unanswered, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line in your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file and restarting samba.

```
[SomeSambaShare]
valid users = SomeUser
```

Comment: I don't want to restrict access to the share but to a subdirectory of a share. The share itself is pretty much available to every user on the network.

Answer (score 0):

[global]

```
invalid users = root bin daemon adm sync shutdown \
                    halt mail news uucp operator
auto services = dave peter bob
```

I would think you could put them in the invalid users list or create an invalid users list in the section you need to restrict.